# using #ifdef for different number of function argument depending on platforms

Tags: c, function, cross-platform

I have a requirement that states a function should take in one new argument at the beginning of the argument list for a new platform I am working on.

so the following would be a prototype for this new platform

```
void foo (int newarg, const char * a, int b, int c);
```

where as in the previous case it was just

```
void foo (const char * a, int b, int c);
```

My concern is readability and code space . So I am thinking of using ifdefs but i am not sure if it is a good idea to use if def with in a argument list.

1)

```
void foo (
#ifdef __NEWPLATFORM__
    int newarg, 
#else
    const char * a, int b, int c
#endif
);
```

or

```
#if __NEWPALTFORM__
    void foo (int newarg, const char * a, int b, int c);
#else
    void foo (const char * a, int b, int c);
#endif
```

Btw I cannot put the new argument to the end of the list which would make it a lot easier.

Which one of the two (or maybe a better solution) is better?

Thanks

Comment: do you have to maintain backwards compatibility of foo?  or are you going to change all the calls to foo too?

Comment: [Careful...](http://i.imgur.com/jz6LF9v.png) ([source](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2014-the-Netherlands/Modernizing-Legacy-C-Code))

Comment: I think Option 1 doesn't work like you think it works.  That `#else` should probably be the `#endif`, and the `#endif` dropped.

Comment: @KeithNicholas When calling foo I'm distinguish platforms using ifdefs, similarly.

Comment: Can you give more detail? Why does the new platform need the extra parameter?

Comment: @ooga the new platforms needs an extra id field to distinguish between  different inputs from similar devices. I'm trying to modify an existing open source code to port it over to another platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are changing all the calls to `foo`,

just change `foo` to the function with more parameters, then `#ifdef` internal to the function for different functionality.

```
void foo (int newarg, const char * a, int b, int c){
   #ifdef __NEWPALTFORM__
   #else
   #endif
}
```

Also worth considering whether the parameters to the function should really be a struct, in which case new parameters in the future won't be much of an issue.   Not enough context in your question to say whether this is a good idea or not

but it would be something like :=

```
typedef struct {
   int newarg;
   const char* a;
   int b;
   int c;
} fooType;

    void foo(fooType f)   // either by value or by pointer depending on context
    {
      // #ifdefs...
    }
```

Comment: Yes I can ignore the first argument for other platforms.  Thanks for the simple solution, this should do.

Answer (score 1):

A third option would be to conditionally define a symbol for the extra argument. You might use the #ifdef section to include other useful platform related stuff, for example:

```
#ifdef MY_NEW_PLATFORM
 #define EXTRA_ARGS int newarg,
 #define GET_EXTRA newarg
 #define SET_EXTRA(val) newarg = (val)
#else
 #define EXTRA_ARGS
 #define GET_EXTRA 0
 #define SET_EXTRA(val)
#endif
```

...

```
void foo (EXTRA_ARGS const char * a, int b, int c) {
  b = GET_EXTRA + c;  /* Just as example */
  SET_EXTRA(b+c);
}
```

As you can see, the foo function has no distracting "#ifdefs", and it compiles in any platform.